# Difficulty adding Go bazel build options for multiple platforms

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

Starting from the example here: https://github.com/PiotrSikora/bazel-zig-cc/blob/main/rules/rules_go.bzl

I am trying to extend it to add the following:

1. Same flags for linux targets
2. "-l" and "-w" for BSD target
3. Add "-trimpath" for all targets

However, I am having difficulty even achieving (1). Here is my code:

```
_MACOS_GC_LINKOPTS = ["-s", "-w", "-buildmode=pie","-trimpath"]
_LINUX_GC_LINKOPTS = ["-s", "-w", "-buildmode=pie","-trimpath"]

def go_binary(**kwargs):
    kwargs["gc_linkopts"] = select({
        "@platforms//os:macos": _MACOS_GC_LINKOPTS,
        "@platforms//os:linux": _LINUX_GC_LINKOPTS,
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }) + kwargs.pop("gc_linkopts", [])
    go_binary_rule(**kwargs)
```

The error I get is:

```
flag provided but not defined: -trimpath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options in the `gc_linkopts` are passed to the [Go linker](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/link). `-trimpath` is an option of the toplevel `go` driver, which `rules_go` bypasses, and the underlying compiler not the linker.

Comment: I see, thanks. That makes sense. Is there an alternative way to pass `-trimpath` that I haven't spotted yet ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish at a high level? rules_go actually passes `-trimpath` for you to the compiler I believe.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case it seems I'm trying to accomplish what has already been accomplished. :)